# Robolectric: how to test class which use application instance inside?

Tags: android, robolectric

I want to test a fragment *UserConnectFragment* which contains a variable *PlateformConnect*. This class has a method to initialise Facebook SDK:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
}
```

I extended Android application with *MyApplication* class.

In *UserConnectFragment*, I use PlateformConnect like that:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Must be done before the content view assignement!
    PlateformConnect.getInstance().create(); 

...
```

In my Robolectric class test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Create basic activity, and add fragment
    mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
    mUserConnectFragment = new UserConnectFragment();
    addMapFragment(mActivity, mUserConnectFragment);

    //mLoginButton = (Button)   mActivity.findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
}
```

There is a crash when this test runs:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxx.yyyy.ui.intro.UserConnectFragment.onViewCreated(UserConnectFragment.java:77)
```

And this error appears because I use:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
```

... and getInstance() returns null.

In my application I use *MyApplication.getInstance()* in a lot of class, so how can I do to test with Robolectric ??

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution: just add @Config(xxx) to set the Application class name.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(application = MyApplication.class)
public class UserConnectFragmentTest {

...
```

More details here: http://robolectric.org/custom-test-runner/

Answer (score 1):

`ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()` worked for me.

Comment: this works but don't forget to add `@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)` above test class declaration.